# Lunch Order Billing Menu

Tags: c#, winforms

Alright so, i have got most of the things working except when i want to order something else like Pizza the Add-On items should change to Pepperoni, Sausage, Olives or Salad the Add-On items should change to  Croutons, Bacon bits, Bread stick but its not changing. Here is what i have got so far:

```
enter code here public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    decimal Subtotal;
    decimal Tax = 0.0775m;
    decimal OrderTotal;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal add = 0m;
        if (chk1.Checked)
        {
            add++;
        }
        if (chk2.Checked)
        {
            add++;
        }
        if (chk3.Checked)
        {
            add++;
        }
        if (rdoHamburger.Checked)
        {
            decimal Hamburger = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoHamburger.Checked);
            Hamburger = 6.95m;

            Subtotal = Hamburger + (add * .75m);
            Tax = Subtotal * 0.0775m;
            OrderTotal = Tax + Subtotal;

            textBox1.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
            textBox2.Text = Tax.ToString("c");
            textBox3.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("c");

        }
        else if (rdoPizza.Checked)
        {

            decimal Pizza = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoPizza.Checked);
            Pizza = 5.95m;

            Subtotal = Pizza + (add * .50m);

            Tax = Subtotal * 0.00775m;

            OrderTotal = Tax + Subtotal;

            textBox1.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
            textBox2.Text = Tax.ToString("c");
            textBox3.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("c");


        }
        else if (rdoSalad.Checked)
        {

            decimal salad = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoSalad.Checked);
            salad = 4.95m;

            Subtotal = salad + (add * .25m);

            Tax = Subtotal * 0.0775m;
            OrderTotal = Tax + Subtotal;
            textBox1.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
            textBox2.Text = Tax.ToString("c");
            textBox3.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("c");
        }
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdoHamburger.Checked)
        {
            gbxAddOnItems.Text = "Add-on items ($.75 each)";
            chk1.Text = "Lettuce, tomato and ketchup";
            chk2.Text = "Ketchup , mustard and mayo";
            chk3.Text = "French fries";

            chk1.Checked = false;
            chk2.Checked = false;
            chk3.Checked = false;

            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();

        }
        else if (rdoPizza.Checked)
        {
            gbxAddOnItems.Text = "Add-on items ($.50 each)";
            chk1.Text = "Pepperoni";
            chk2.Text = "Sausage";
            chk3.Text = "Olives";

            chk1.Checked = false;
            chk2.Checked = false;
            chk3.Checked = false;

            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();

        }
        else if (rdoSalad.Checked)
        {
            gbxAddOnItems.Text = "Add-on items ($.25 each)";
            chk1.Text = "Croutons";
            chk2.Text = "Bacon bits";
            chk3.Text = "Bread Sticks";

            chk1.Checked = false;
            chk2.Checked = false;
            chk3.Checked = false;

            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
        }
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "Thank You for Using Our Service!\n Would You Like use our service again?";
        DialogResult button =
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Dear Customer",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (button == DialogResult.No)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        if (button == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thank You!! \n We Hope you will come Soon!", "Greeting      Message");
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

...

[image: Image of the project i want to get done]

I would be grateful if anyone could help have 2 days left.

Comment: Bit of an odd choice to key it off `groupBox1_Enter`  I think I'd have attached it to checked events of the radio buttons

Comment: Subscribe to CheckedChanged? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged

Comment: Also, this is odd: `decimal Pizza = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoPizza.Checked);
            Pizza = 5.95m;` - converting a bool to decimal isn't something that really makes sense, and then overworking it immediately with something else.. you should just straight set `decimal Pizza = 5.95m;`. In c# local variables should be named with camelCase , not PascalCase

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.refresh() or Application.DoEvents()?

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is almost never the answer

Comment: Yes, however it did not work

Answer (score 0):

you problem is that you are updating that menu using the Enter event. This is triggered if the user tabs into that control see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

This is not what you want , you want to run that update code based on the click events of the pizza / etc checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

please use `CheckedChanged` event of RadioButtons,

```
private void rdoHamburger_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chk1.Text = "Lettuce, tomato and ketchup";
    chk2.Text = "Ketchup , mustard and mayo";
    chk3.Text = "French fries";
}

private void rdoPizza_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chk1.Text = "Pepperoni";
    chk2.Text = "Sausage";
    chk3.Text = "Olives";
}

private void rdoSalad_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chk1.Text = "Croutons";
    chk2.Text = "Bacon bits";
    chk3.Text = "Bread Sticks";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).